# Can the out focus stop the call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok so I have an autocomplete field [heere](http://doorsplit.heroku.com/) that is making an ajax request every keystroke...But the .focusout() should kill the autocomplete because intuitively if the user leaves the field and moves on the next field it should not give you any suggestions bacause you already left the field. Any ideas on how to do this. Here is my code. I am using this autocomplete [plugin](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) and here is my code the credentials. Enter an artist and leave the field to see what i mean

email: test@test.com pass: test12

```
$('#request_artist').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: '<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>',
  minChars:1,
  width: 300,
  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
  params: { artists: 'Yes' },
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **[abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29)**:

```
var theCall = $('#request_artist').autocomplete({
                  serviceUrl: '<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>',
                  minChars:1,
                  width: 300,
                  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
                  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
                  params: { artists: 'Yes' },
                 });
// ...
// When you decide you want to cancel the call
$('#request_artist').blur(function() { 

    theCall.abort();

});
```

Taken from this **[previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery/446626#446626)**. The above will only work if, `.autoComplete()` uses an `XMLHttpRequest` instance to make the call.